cocartesian Fibrations
I need to show that that a cocartesian fibration between $\infty$-categories $p: C\to D$ s.t all fibers are equivalent to $\Delta^0$ is an acyclic Kan fibration.
I am really not sure how to do that. I tried the following (but I am not sure this is true). I know that for a cocartesian fibration, every fiber is an anima iff all morphisms in $D$ are cocartesian. As every fiber is equivalent to $\Delta^0$ this is especially an anima hence I can apply this in this case. Now as every morphism is cocartesian by the definition of a cocartesian morphism, I should find lifting against every map $\Lambda_0^n \to \Delta^n$. I can fill inner horns always, as I am working with $\infty$-categories (but I don't want to fill them, I want to fill them against $p$, is this so easy?). What about $\Lambda_n^n$, how can I fill these ones in order to show that this is a Kan complex. Moreover how can I proof the acyclic part?
Would appreciate if what I have written is correct, and how to go on (if it is).

This seems like an exercise from a book or something, so my question is: are you "allowed" to use the straightening-unstraightening equivalence? Alternatively, are you allowed to use the fact that a morphism between cocartesian fibrations is an equivalence precisely when it is fiberwise one?

yes we did Luries straightening/unstraightening theorem, even thought I dont completly get that by now, I assume it is important for this?

An alternative answer that uses straightening goes as follows. First note that a cocartesian fibration has lifting against inner horns by definition, so you don't need to worry about those. In fact, it is a fibration in the Joyal model structure, and hence to show it is a trivial fibration it suffices, as Thorgott already wrote, to show it is a Joyal equivalence.
Straightening-unstraightening tells you that a cocartesian fibration with domain $D$ gives you a functor $D\to\mathrm{Cat}_\infty$ by taking fibers, and that this functor determines the cocartesian fibration up to equivalence. Suppose $F\colon D\to\mathrm{Cat}_\infty$ is the functor associated to $p$, and write $G\colon D\to\mathrm{Cat}_\infty$ for the constant functor on $\Delta^0$. This is terminal in $\mathrm{Fun}(D,\mathrm{Cat}_\infty)$, so we obtain a natural transformation $\eta\colon F\to G$. You are given that the fibers of $p$ are all Joyal contractible, so $Fd\simeq p^{-1}(d)$ is Joyal contractible for any $d\in D$. Hence $\eta$ is objectwise an equivalence, from which we conclude that $F\simeq G$. However, it is not hard to see that the constant functor $G$ is classified by the cocartesian fibration $\mathrm{id}\colon D\to D$. So straightening-unstraightening implies that there is a Joyal equivalence $C\simeq D$ commuting with the two maps $p\colon C\to D$ and $\mathrm{id}\colon D\to D$. This forces $p$ to be a Joyal equivalence, and we are done.

what means Joyal contractibel (in difference to contractibel? And can you explan why $\eta$ is an equivalence objectwise.

$X$ is Joyal contractible when the map $X \to \Delta^0$ is a Joyal equivalence. I said this to emphasize which kind of weak equivalence I was considering, because people might think "contractible" means that $X\to\Delta^0$ is a (Kan) weak homotopy equivalence. $\eta$ is objectwise an equivalence because any map between contractible objects is a weak equivalence: this follows from 2-out-of-3 applied to the map in question and the two maps from your objects toward the terminal object, that are both weak equivalences. Or because $\eta$ at the object $X$ in this case is the map $X\to\Delta^0$.

Hint: Combine

A cocartesian fibration (more generally, categorical fibration) between $\infty$-categories is a trivial fibration iff it is a categorical equivalence.

A functor of $\infty$-categories is a categorical equivalence if and only if it is fully faithful and essentially surjective.

For a categorical fibration $p\colon\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ between $\infty$-categories, the induced map $\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(x,y)\rightarrow\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{D}}(px,py)$ is a Kan fibration and, if $p$ is furthermore a cocartesian fibration, its (homotopy) fiber over $f\colon px\rightarrow py$ can be described as $\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}_{py}}(y^{\prime},y)\rightarrow\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(x,y)$, pre-composition with a $p$-cocartesian lift $\tilde{f}\colon x\rightarrow y^{\prime}$ of $f$.


(Note also that the hypotheses are stable under pullback and a trivial fibration is defined by lifting problems whose base is an $\infty$-category, so, since our map is an inner fibration anyways, we see that the statement readily generalizes to cocartesian fibrations between arbitrary simplicial sets.)
